# Cuáles son las formas de escribir PHP en HTML

Tags: php, html

*Actualización:*
Tengo problemas con mi código con sintaxis de operador ternario, me sale mi página en blanco, lo que quiero es que muestre algo así:

> ?18299012

```
<?= $hotel['cache'] ? "?" rand() : ""?>
```

Comment: Hola, no entiendo tu duda, te recomendaría leer [ask], ¿nos explicarías mejor lo que tratas de lograr así como las dudas claras que tienes?

Comment: Lo que quería decir, es como funciona esta variable <?php echo (DEBUGGING) ? date('_Y-m-d_H:i:s') : ""; ?>. Qué significa el '?' y el ':' e etc

Comment: Haría falta ver que hace la constante `DEBUGGING` por que la sintaxis que dices es el operador ternario `$variable ? valorVerdadero : valorFalso;`

Comment: Gracias por decirme el nombre de la sintaxis, lo de DEBUGGIN era un ejemplo nada más. Yo hice mi propio código pero quiero agregar antes del rand() un '?' pero queda en blanco mi página <?= $hotel['cache'] ? "?" rand() : ""?>. Para que quede algo así: ?1231902

Comment: Considero entonces deberías editar tu pregunta, colocando lo que deseas lograr exactamente así como lo que llevas hasta el momento para que de este modo comprendamos mejor como ayudarte amigo :D

Comment: Listo, gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te está faltando el `.` para concatenar el `?` con el `rand()`. Debería ser así: `$hotel['cache'] ? '?' . rand() : ''`.

Answer (score 3):

Hay varias cosas que debes corregir en tu expresión de operador ternario:

1) La comparacion debe estar encerrado en parentesis

2) Falta indicar con que estas comparando el array

3) La llamada de php se recomienda usar **`<?php ?>`**

4) Para concatenar el caracter con el random debes usar un **punto .**

5) Te falta usar un **echo** para la salida

Te coloco este ejemplo de código para que revises:

```
<?php echo  ($hotel['cache']=='x')? '?' . rand() : ""; ?>
```

Comment: Me temo que varios puntos no son del todo correctos, php permite varias de las practicas mostradas en la pregunta, por ejemplo `<?=` es lo mismo que `<?php echo`, esta habilitado por defecto desde la versión 5.4 sin importar el `php.ini`. Referencias : https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: La comparación puede no estar entre paréntesis. No hace falta comprar el array con algo, en sí mismo va a ser evaluado como boolean. El `echo` está implícito en la sintaxis `<?=`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, es bueno saber que se puede optimizar mucho mas el codigo, tomare en cuenta la sintaxis mas simplificada.